# Google sheets function importJSON returning objects in new columns

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm using Google Sheets to create a table with some data collected via API. I'm using the importJSON function (available At https://gist.github.com/chrislkeller/5719258) to import this data.

The JSON the function gets has this kind of structure:

```
{
"id": "76d8fs7fg78sf6gs876fg8as4",
"name": "aaaaaaaaaaaa",
"platform": "ios",
"ad_format": "INTER",
"package_name": "com.site.game",
"has_active_experiment": true,
"disabled": false,
"ad_network_settings": [
    {
        "ADCOLONY_NETWORK": {
            "disabled": false,
            "targets": {},
            "ad_network_ad_units": [
                {
                    "ad_network_ad_unit_id": "qwekhrbqkwer",
                    "disabled": false,
                    "cpm": "3.00",
                    "countries": {
                        "type": "INCLUDE",
                        "values": [
                            "ca",
                            "nz",
                            "se"
                }
            ],
            "ad_network_app_id": "123456"
        }
    },
    {
        "ADMOB_NETWORK": {
            "disabled": false,
            "targets": {},
            "ad_network_ad_units": [
                {
                    "ad_network_ad_unit_id": "ca-624",
                    "extraParameters": null,
                    "disabled": false,
                    "cpm": "37.00",
                    "countries": {
                        "type": "INCLUDE",
                        "values": [
                            "ca",
                            "ch",
                            "gb",
                            "no",
                            "nz",
                            "se"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "ad_network_ad_unit_id": "ca-036",
                    "extraParameters": null,
                    "disabled": false,
                    "cpm": "36.00",
                    "countries": {
                        "type": "INCLUDE",
                        "values": [
                            "au",
                            "us"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "ad_network_ad_unit_id": "ca-28",
                    "extraParameters": null,
                    "disabled": false,
                    "cpm": "7.80",
                    "countries": {
                        "type": "EXCLUDE",
                        "values": [
                            "ae",
                            "at"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "ad_network_ad_unit_id": "ca-82",
                    "extraParameters": null,
                    "disabled": false,
                    "cpm": "6.50",
                    "countries": {
                        "type": "INCLUDE",
                        "values": [
                            "au",
                            "us"
                        ]
                    }
                },

                {
                    "ad_network_ad_unit_id": "ca-65",
                    "extraParameters": null,
                    "disabled": false,
                    "cpm": "4.00",
                    "countries": {
                        "type": "EXCLUDE",
                        "values": [
                            "ae",
                            "at",
                            "au"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ],
            "ad_network_app_id": "ca-03"
        }
    },
    {
        "APPLOVIN_NETWORK": {
            "disabled": false,
            "targets": {},
            "ad_network_ad_units": []
        }
    },
    },
    {
            ],
            "ad_network_app_id": "458"
        }
    }
]
```

}

The problem is that after parsing the data, it creates a table with new columns for every  object in the JSON, like:

```
id
name
platform
ad_format
package_name
has_active_experiment
disabled
ad_network_settings/ADCOLONY_NETWORK/disabled
ad_network_settings/ADCOLONY_NETWORK/ad_network_ad_units/ad_network_ad_unit_id
ad_network_settings/ADCOLONY_NETWORK/ad_network_ad_units/disabled
ad_network_settings/ADCOLONY_NETWORK/ad_network_app_id
ad_network_settings/ADMOB_NETWORK/disabled
ad_network_settings/ADMOB_NETWORK/ad_network_ad_units/ad_network_ad_unit_id
ad_network_settings/ADMOB_NETWORK/ad_network_ad_units/extraParameters
ad_network_settings/ADMOB_NETWORK/ad_network_ad_units/disabled
ad_network_settings/ADMOB_NETWORK/ad_network_ad_units/cpm
ad_network_settings/ADMOB_NETWORK/ad_network_ad_units/countries/type
ad_network_settings/ADMOB_NETWORK/ad_network_ad_units/countries/values
ad_network_settings/ADMOB_NETWORK/ad_network_app_id
ad_network_settings/APPLOVIN_NETWORK/disabled
ad_network_settings/APPLOVIN_NETWORK/ad_network_ad_units
ad_network_settings/FACEBOOK_NETWORK/disabled
ad_network_settings/FACEBOOK_NETWORK/ad_network_ad_units/ad_network_ad_unit_id
ad_network_settings/FACEBOOK_NETWORK/ad_network_ad_units/disabled
ad_network_settings/IRONSOURCE_NETWORK/disabled
ad_network_settings/IRONSOURCE_NETWORK/ad_network_ad_units/ad_network_ad_unit_id
ad_network_settings/IRONSOURCE_NETWORK/ad_network_ad_units/extraParameters
ad_network_settings/IRONSOURCE_NETWORK/ad_network_ad_units/disabled
ad_network_settings/IRONSOURCE_NETWORK/ad_network_ad_units/cpm
```

When what i want to get is a table with the following structure as columns:

```
id
name
platform
ad_format
package_name
has_active_experiment
disabled
ad_network_settings_network_name (like in the example: ADCOLONY_NETWORK, ADMOB_NETWORK, APPLOVIN_NETWORK, etc)
ad_network_settings_disabled
ad_network_settings_targets
ad_network_settings_ad_network_ad_unit_id
ad_network_settings_ad_network_extra_parameters
ad_network_settings_ad_network_disabled
ad_network_settings_ad_network_cpm
ad_network_settings_ad_network_countries_type
ad_network_settings_ad_network_countries_values
```

Meaning I want the name of the networks in a new column to avoid multiple columns with the same information structure for each network.

I tried adding a **for** clause in the function to call each object in ad_network_settings at a time, but i couldn't get it working.

Any ideas on how I could get it work?
I'm sorry I cant share the API endpoint here so you can try it, but I can't share this kind of info for safety measures.

Comment: Im also tweaking the **else if (isObject_(value))** under parseData_ function, but with no success.